# Sidebox with tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, minipage

I'm searching for a package, that can produce an overlay colorbox that goes to the right side and it would be still possible to right on the left side.

With the package `tcolorbox` and the option `enlarge by left by=` it seemed possible, but here I can't use the left side for any additional text.

Any ideas?

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper, titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=0cm,
    right=0cm,
    top=0cm,
    bottom=0cm,
}
\definecolor{sideframe}{RGB}{110, 110, 110}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{
    enhanced,
    breakable, 
    width=67mm,
    height=300mm,
    right=5mm,
    colframe=gray!235!black,
    colback=sideframe,
    arc=0mm
}

% Text
\begin{minipage}[t]{10cm}
    Title
\end{minipage}

% Side box
\begin{tcolorbox}[enlarge left by=15cm]
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{FlushRight}
                \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Contact}} \\
            \end{FlushRight}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The plain TeX macro package `insbox` might help.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: Where is environment `FlushRight` defined?